is ng-grid.js CSP compatible?
I am using the ng-grid.js library in my AngularJS project and need to verify if setTimeout and eval() are functioning correctly after removing unsafe-eval from the Content Security Policy:
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' http: https: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';"/>

What I Have Tried:

I attempted to debug the usage of setTimeout and eval() but did not observe expected behavior.
Checked the browser console for errors.
Verified that all JavaScript
files are loaded correctly.
Ensured that the modal is being triggered
and shown correctly.

